# Perfect 9-sided die

Tags: mathematics, geometry, dice, algebra

I am working on a fair 9-sided die and I settled on a design where you select three edges of a cube where the two sides that one edge touches don't overlap with any of the other sides touched by the other edges, then chamfer those edges off. This results in three rectangular faces (previously edges) and six irregular pentagonal faces (previously squares), and I thought it would be as simple as making all the faces have the same area. But no, when I did that, the rectangular faces (or at least their centers) were closer to the center of gravity than the pentagonal faces, and so were landed on more often than the pentagonal faces (or at least the rectangular faces landed as the base of the dice, and an edge on the top of the dice.) I'm relatively sure that the solution to this problem is to divide the area of the rectangular face by the distance of that face's center to the center of mass, do the same for the irregular pentagonal faces, then make those two ratios the same.

[image: Geometric Image] Assuming that B is the center point of the first shape, A is the area of the first shape, and A' is the area of the second shape, find a solution that satisfies this equation: A/D=A'/D'

Please help, I'm not that good at math.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this doesn't look like a math *puzzle*, which we require to be at least somewhat planned/with elegant solutions. This site is, unfortunately, not a die-design service.

Comment: would there be somewhere better fitting for me to ask this question?

Comment: I don’t know very much about center of gravity so I don’t know if your design will work.  But you can make a fair 9-sided die by making a 9-sided prism with all faces equal and all angles between the faces equal AND you do something to ensure that the die won’t land on either end.  For example, you could put a hemisphere on each end.

Comment: Another possibility is to use two regular cubical dice modified with the following non-standard numbering:  Die 1 is labelled 0, 0, 3, 3, 6, 6 and Die 2 is labelled 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3.  To simulate a 9-sided die, you randomly throw Die 1 and Die 2 and sum the two numbers shown.  Each possible sum (1, 2, 3, ... 9) is equally likely.

Comment: If the shape is not face transitive, then it is very hard to say whether something is a fair die. A lot depends on how it is thrown  (whether you roll it or keep it in a dice cup). Even if the faces are all the same and have the same angles, [it might still not be fair](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3156614/362967).

Comment: You could make a 9-sided spinner die like this [6-sided spinner](https://i.pinimg.com/564x/d7/b6/31/d7b631135cc2c97eb08d482c3cbcb24c--spinning-top-board-games.jpg). Or, you could use a regular [dodecahedral die](https://math.andyou.com/content/08/02/images/mu_pe_08_02_001.png) and throw it again if you get a 10, 11 or 12. Or a [barrel die](https://dicecreator.files.wordpress.com/2010/05/barrel-d10.jpg).

Comment: The question might be good on SE [Board & Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @WeatherVane  from my knowledge their game-design questions skew towards mechanics over mathematical modeling of dice - do you have edge-case experience I'm missing?

Comment: @bobble I thought the reason behind the question is about how to actually make or obtain a fair 9-sided die.

Comment: @WeatherVane perhaps that's the motivation, but as of now the question is asking specifically to solve the given mathematical equation.

Comment: I will be leaving this up for now in case someone who saw this figures this out, but I will be reposting it on math stack exchange